# What is the difference between digital input with low bias and digital input with high bias?

Tags: voltage, digital-logic, operational-amplifier, input

I have 3 inputs. Input #1 is low bias. I can hook up a 12V positive to input 1 and it will change it's state to 1 (or input is ON).

Inputs #2 and #3 are high bias. Connecting a 12VDC to either of these inputs causes no change in state.

The description for these two inputs describes +12v via 100kΩ res, with a 2V threshold. I can't change the "high" state on these two inputs.

What kind of input is expected on inputs 2 and 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two inputs are internally pulled up to the voltage rail using 100k resistors.  In this case, you want to connect them to ground to activate the input.  I'm unsure if you need to 1) pull them down 2V (to 10V), or 2) have to pull them down to 2V or lower.

If you wish to do this with a microcontroller that doesn't have a suitable output that runs from 0V to 12V, you can use an npn transistor or an n-channel mosfet.

This type of input is also referred to as "active-low".

Answer (score 2):

For inputs 2 and 3 (normally high) you just need a contact closure to ground to pull the inputs low.  If they have a low threshold of 2 volts, you just need to pull the inputs below 2 volts to have them recognized as Low.